# easy way to run code inside a loop every nth time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a piece of code every 7th iteration inside my for loop.

How would I do this?

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  if (i == 7) {
    console.log('7 iterations have passed')
  }

  console.log(i)
}
```

Currently it only does it once, I'm not sure what's the clean way of checking this.

Comment: `if ((i % 7) === 0)`

Comment: You need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: Use `i += 7` instead of `i++`

Answer (score 5):

With the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    if (i % 7 === 0) {
        console.log(i +' iterations have passed')
    }

    console.log(i)
}
```